# Get Blob data from an API using Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, blob

Downloading a file from api - it returns a blob which is then downloaded.
The below code is from axios call from React.js

```
const downloadFile = () => {
  axios.get(apiUrl`,
  {
   responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    let filename = 'somefile.pdf';
    console.log("this is from axios")
    console.log((response.data))
    console.log(typeof(response.data))
    const urld = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = urld;
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(urld);
    link.remove();  
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

The pdf gets downloaded and the response type is "Blob" object as below

```
Blob{size: 169929, type: 'application/octet-stream'}
```

The same axios call done using Express.js gives response as string

```
app.get('/proxyapi/crop/advisory/file',function (req, res) {
  axios.get(apiUrl`,
  {
   responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("this is from express")
    console.log((response.data))
    console.log(typeof(response.data))  
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
})
```

The response here is string with below format data

```
data: '%PDF-1.7\n' +
    '%����\n' +
    '5 0 obj\n' +
    '<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 3331>>stream\n' +
    'x���Ms�6\x12���\x158�Uc�\x00A��i%;N��l��M.��\x1AJb<\x1F\n' +
    'g�-��/��n\x023�J�\\�.�O��nt�\x1C�ϳ��\x7F��Y�\x16�&mY\x15MM�gu-�\x07k���\x14�䅲*`�g��\x1E��s�g�B�\x077\r/�փ�I��\x1F�"Ͷ��U��U�\x1C�P\x07B\x03�\x1A���\x05�s�\x06���;��=%����3��B4�i�\x13�ny����o\x1F�����\x1F��:���US\x18=V�*HqV|n>x\b]UE�\x02Z�e3���d�\x06�3��U\n' +
    '\x1DL($�\x19Dv:�D<\x1C\x18��ܲ)*&\x7F]Zp�9c�\f��\x16�F�B}����9;�,X\x1E�4\x11X�e�Q�"E5��W��V!\x06Gv88\x13\n' +
    `��ј�\x1E�BZ\x12���u!\x04i䏎�Mp9�Vd�=O�\x02\x11%��G\t\x0BՉ\x11Ԥ����@T@;�\x16�օ<a!\x19�����cU"t0�\x10� �\x10קf�z�\x07�H�mt*C^�\r�~\\�����\x0E����0�ϯn��8l��_'���ϭB]k\x1CU|]�q1\x05;>9S�\x11X��h�\n` +
    '\x17mYtIG��\x04Ղ|�\x07�Q�� .....'
```

How do you convert this to a Blob?
Also how to send this data as a blob if another function calls this express-js api/route is triggered.

The file type can vary, currently trying with just pdf.